# Clarifications for SSH tunnels over HTTP (or HTTPS)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, http, hosts, tunneling

I noticed that when I create a tunnel locally from my PC to the remote one, for some devices (generally routers), the connection via http or https does not take place. I get a pop-up that says:

```
The 'Host' field contained in Http header is invalid
```

If setting the following in the file `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 modemtim
```

and I connect using **modemtim** and not only **127.0.0.1**, everything works correctly.

SSH command:

```
ssh -L 8080:<IP_REMOTE_ROUTER>:80 <USER>@<REMOTE_TUNNEL>
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical http request looks like this if you connect to http://google.com/?q=icarus

```
GET /?q=icarus HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
User-Agent: mozilla/123
Accept: */*
```

Low cost web service providers host many many domains such as www.yourdomain.name and www.mydomain.us on a single machine. The web server on that machine looks at the `Host:` header to see which set of files to use. If you connect to http://127.0.0.1/index.html and this is forwarded to www.yourdomain.name the remote webserver will have a `Host: 127.0.0.1` header which doesn't help it decide which set of files is wanted. Adding an entry to /etc/hosts and making the request to http://www.yourdomain.name/index.html fixes this issue.

Comment: but shouldn't ssh think about setting the correct ip?  that ip 127.0.0.0.1 is about my pc ... why doesn't ssh change that ip in the ip of the remote server?

Comment: This is nothing to do with ssh. You are telling your browser to go to http://127.0.0.1/whatever, so you browser sets the `Host:` header in the request to 127.0.0.1.  Your browser then goes to your pc. ssh is just used to tunnel the bytes between the endpoints, it doesn't alter them. The closest ssh comes to fixing things is the X forwarding.